# Can server sends more than one responds to client's request?

Tags: java, client, protocols

I am learning socket and server/client model concept and having a hard time understanding the server client concept. If a client sends a request, can server sends more than one respond? Or we have to put everything in one respond? 
For a memory game program, when a client click a card, the action will send a request to server in order to turn the card in every player's program, if the second card does not match,  the server tells players wait 2 secs, turn the 2 cards back, and then assign turn to next player. Can a server does this in multiple responds or it has to do it in single respond? Since no client requests for some responds, so I don't know if it is achievable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about TCP connections, after the connection has established client and server are equivalent, both are free to send data as long and as much they like and/or shut down their end of the connection.

Edit: After several passes I think i have understood what the second paragraph of your question is aiming for.
There is, of course, nothing which would stop the server from doing anything.. What your server seems to do, most of the time, is blocking on a InputStream.read() operation.  If you want the server to operate even when no network input happens, one solution might be to use a read timeout, or check the input stream for readability before actually reading.

Comment: Edit: In the first half of the question, the OP talks about client and server, as if there was a difference with respect to I/O. I felt i should point out there's not.  The second half did not make sense to me until i re-read (hence the edit).

Answer (score 0):

This is not your complete answer.
For one request, you get one response back.

Please read on this information in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request-response) for the basics

*"Request-response, also known as request-reply, is a message exchange pattern in which a requestor sends a request message to a replier system which receives and processes the request, ultimately returning a message in response. This is a simple, but powerful messaging pattern which allows two applications to have a two-way conversation with one another over a channel. This pattern is especially common in client-server architectures.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request-response)
For simplicity, this pattern is typically implemented in a purely synchronous fashion, as in web service calls over HTTP, which holds a connection open and waits until the response is delivered or the timeout period expires. However, request-response may also be implemented asynchronously, with a response being returned at some unknown later time. This is often referred to as "sync over async", or "sync/async", and is common in enterprise application integration (EAI) implementations where slow aggregations, time-intensive functions, or human workflow must be performed before a response can be constructed and delivered."*